# How to use child class to change parents property

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm trying to change a property in my parent class with my child class but I'm not getting the result I'm expecting. 
I've done some research (like [Change parent variable from child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219859/change-parent-variable-from-child-class)), but I can't seem to find the problem.

```
class A {
    public $msg;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->msg = 'foo';
    }

    public function setMessage($string) {
        $this->msg = $string;
    }

    public function getMessage() {
        var_dump($this->msg); // For demo purposes
    }

    public function triggerB() {
        $b = new B;
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::setMessage('bar');
    }
}

$a = new A;
$a->getMessage();
$a->triggerB();
$a->getMessage();
```

The output I get is "foo" twice and I expect it to be "foo" "bar".

Could anyone explain me what i'm doing wrong and how I can fix this?
In my actual code I want the child-class to validate some $_POST values, and return the outcome to the Main-class. The parent uses the child to validate.

Comment: First of all, if you wish to call a constructor, use paranthesis, e.g. `new B()`. Second, you are creating instances, they have no reference to eachother. I guess you are thinking _statically_, which isn't the purpose of orientating in objects ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having your object `A` and creating an instance of it and storing it in the variable `$a`, in the global scope. And then you are creating another instance of your class `B` and storing it in a variable `$b` which is in the scope of the method `triggerB()`.

You can only change the properties of the parent class `A` if you pass an argument to your another class `B`.

So something like this should suffice:

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);
class A {
    public $msg;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->msg = 'foo';
    }

    public function setMessage(string $string) {
        $this->msg = $string;
    }

    public function getMessage() {
        var_dump($this->msg); // For demo purposes
    }

    public function triggerB() {
        (new B($this));
    }
}
class B {
    public function __construct(A $a) {
        $a->msg = "bar";
    }
}

$a = new A;
$a->getMessage();
$a->triggerB();
$a->getMessage();
```

This approach is better suited to readability and better dependency management.

---

Another approach:

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);
class A {
    public $msg;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->msg = 'foo';
    }

    public function setMessage(string $string) {
        $this->msg = $string;
    }

    public function getMessage() {
        var_dump($this->msg); // For demo purposes
    }

    public function triggerB() {
        $this->msg = 'bar';
    }
}
class B {
    public function __construct(A $a) {
        $a->msg = "bar";
    }
}

$a = new A;
$a->getMessage();
$a->triggerB();
$a->getMessage();
```

This is performance wise better, but if you are going to be doing something complex, the first method is better.

---

Note: The above code is for PHP7.

Comment: Thanks, How is this performance-wise(eg what if class is big)? And is this a good practice? It seems odd.

Comment: The best possible way would be to set the property of the class in the same method as `triggerB()` like - `public function triggerB() { $this->msg = 'Bar'; }` but if you are going to do something complex and some processing, the readability of code should matter the most than performance, and this approach would be better suited.

Answer (score 1):

Your `triggerB()` method does not actually do anything:

```
public function triggerB() {
    $b = new B;
}
```

You are creating a new object and assign that to the `$b` variable. As soon as the method finishes, the `$b` variable / object ceases to exist.

Also note that the `$b` variable in your method is is no way related to the `$a` variable in the global scope so setting any of its properties has no influence on `$a`.